# Adobe Flex i18n working properly in Google Chrome, not in other browsers

Tags: apache-flex, internationalization, flex3

I have developed an i18n sample program in Adobe Flex [SDK 3.5V, Adobe Flash Builder 4]. The program which I have developed is correct and I am getting correct output in Google Chrome. In other browsers [IE, Firefox] instead of the local language, they are showing boxes, which we can't read. Whereas Google Chrome is showing the local language. The browsers and Flash player are the latest version.

Note: browsers are configured with local languages in settings. I am able to see local language in the browsers [IE, firefox] other than the sample flex program [eg: Google local language site].

How can I proceed further to solve this problem?